# Seaborn heatmap auto sizing the cells

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to build a heat map which is working great if there are lot of categorical variables but not looking great when there are two to three data points as shown in the second image. I am looking for a way to auto adjust based on the data points.

[image]

[image]

here is the function

```
def bivariate(col1,col2,Title,cbar_size):
    temp2=modifiedloan.groupby([col1,col2,'loan_status']).id.agg('count').to_frame('count').reset_index()
    temp3=temp2.pivot_table(index=(col1,col2), columns='loan_status', values='count').fillna(0)
    temp3['default%']=(temp3[0]/(temp3[0]+temp3[1]))
    temp3=temp3.reset_index()
    
    temp4=temp3.pivot_table(index=col1, columns=col2, values='default%').fillna(0)
    temp5=temp3.pivot_table(index=col1, columns=col2, values=[0]).fillna(0)
    f, (ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(12,6))

    cmap = sns.cm.rocket_r
    sns.heatmap(temp4,linewidths=1, ax=ax1,annot=False, fmt='g',cmap=cmap,cbar=True,cbar_kws={"shrink": cbar_size})

    sns.heatmap(temp5, annot=True, annot_kws={'va':'top'}, fmt="", cbar=False,ax=ax1)
    sns.heatmap(temp4, annot=True,  fmt=".1%",annot_kws={'va':'bottom'}, cbar=False,cmap=cmap)

    plt.ylim(b, t) # update the ylim(bottom, top) values    
    ax1.set_title(Title)


    plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized the problem is with the version of seaborn installed. The same functions worked well on one of my colleagues machine.